# $_GET breaks modal box

Tags: javascript, php

I have a modal box form that uses an id from a foreach loop. I send the id to the url and use $_GET to retrieve it and assign it to a variable for the form.

However the modal box opens for a second and then closes. I believe the id is not being passed through as for the split second it is open I see an error which I think is undefined variable on the id.

I need some fresh eyes to see what I might be missing and give me an idea of how to fix this problem.

```
<a href="<?php echo doc_root('new_customer.php?model_id=' . $model['id']); ?>"><button class="modal_button customer_button right">New Customer</button></a>


<div class="modal" id="type3">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-title"><h3>New Customer</h3></div> 
<?php

if(isset($_GET['model_id']) && !empty($_GET['model_id'])) {
    $model_id = $_GET['model_id'];
} 

?>

    </div>
</div>

<script>

$(".modal_button").click(function(){
   $(".modal").hide();
   var Type = $(this).data("modal-type");
   $("#"+Type).show();

});
$('.modal ').click(function(){
     $('.modal, .inner').hide();

})                                            
$('.modal-content').click(function(e){
   e.stopPropagation();
})  

</script>
```

Comment: And what does `$_GET` have to do with anything here? Does this work when there is no `$_GET['model_id'];`? Also - you've shown a snippet.  I'm wondering - is the javascript getting repeated on the page somehow?

Comment: clicking the button hides .modal - is this the issue ` $(".modal").hide();` ?

Comment: There's way too much code to post here so I've had to reduce it to the important bits... I have a form in the modal box which uses the foreach $model{'id'] to populate the field $customer['model_id']. The $(".modal").hide(); closes the modal if the user clicks anywhere apart from the modal box. This works fine on my other modal boxes.